# ng2-bootstrap - timepicker change() event not working

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

While using Angular 2's ng2-bootstrap plugin I cannot get the timepicker `change()` event to work. This can be demonstrated on the example page (http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#/timepicker).

In the "typescript" section of the example page you will find the `changed()` function. When you `(change)` a timepicker the console log will not fire, which shows that the `changed()` function is never called.

```
// template:
<timepicker [(ngModel)]="mytime" (change)="changed()" [hourStep]="hstep" 
            [minuteStep]="mstep" [showMeridian]="ismeridian" 
            [readonlyInput]="!isEnabled"></timepicker>

// @Component:
public changed():void {
  console.log('Time changed to: ' + this.mytime);
};
```

Am I misunderstanding how timepicker's `(change)` event is implemented or is the event broken?

Comment: Have you tried using `(ngModelChange)`?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Thats nice! IT works.. Tons of thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Have you tried using `(ngModelChange)`?

As [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6677986/stefan-svrkota) mentioned above, using `(ngModelChange)` will fix the problem.

Comment: This really helped me because (timeChanged) was not working